# Oracle, how to declare local variable inside executable block

Tags: oracle, plsql

Typically variables are declared in the `DECLARE` section, and are available inside `BEGIN` block. I find this style stiff and tedious.

Is it possible to declare variables *inside* the `BEGIN` block just when they are needed? It is stupid to declare new global variable, if it's needed just to store some temporary value for further calculations, queries and assertions.

Comment: They are not global variables, they are local to the program unit.

Answer (score 2):

Try this - I added comments in the code for you to understand the visibility domain of each variable. Also you can remove the comment from the last DBMS_OUTPUT to see that var2 is no longer available in the outer code.

```
set serveroutput on;
<<tag>>        
DECLARE 
  var1 INT := 1; -- global variable
BEGIN  
  DECLARE 
     var1 INT := 2; -- local variable
     var2 INT := 0;
  BEGIN   
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var1); -- will display 2 (value of local var1);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tag.var1); -- will display 1 (value of global var1);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var2); -- will display 0 (value of local var2);
  END;  
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var1); -- will display 1 (value of global var1); 
 -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var2); -- will crash since var2 is no longer in memory;
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

All languages have own features. This is only instrument.
May be you should divide your code into small chunks(procedures, functions)? If your code placed in 20-30 rows, you will not have problems with declaring variables. From smaller chuncks you can build bigger and reusable code.

Regards